# Implementing Entity

Tags: java, jpa, entitylisteners

I am marking some of JPA class with predefined interface say Auditable. Now I want to invoke EntityListeners Auditor  @PrePersist marked method. This has to be done to only those entity which implements this interface. I can see we can do this on Parent Classes but are interface allowed ?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you are trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: Yes, interface is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using interface is wrong here it is you must use abstract class ,interface is just used to represent class behavior not persistent field. by the way try see eclipse link they support additional thing in interface.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces